# How to execute automatically set of dozens of commands on remote server

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, terminator

I am looking how to perform automatically some sets of commands on customer RH servers. Unfortunately I cannot store scripts on the customers servers and I am connecting via some jump hosts so I cannot keep script on my PC neither (it will be complicate to manage accesses for all customers differently in the script). I have experimenting with terminator where it is possible to add commands in custom_command field, but the problem is that all commands are in one line and it is not readable enough in case if you are executing 50 commands. I have also tried with MobaXterm as it supports macros, works well but there isn't version for Linux.

Is there any way how to add multiple commands on separate lines in terminator profile, to copy commands from some local file, or to create macro in some other terminal tool?

Thanks!

Comment: If it's a lot of commands, write them into a script and `scp` it to the remote server, then use `ssh` to log in and execute it. For anything more than just a cursory few things you will probably benefit from a structured script with error handling and logging, etc.

Comment: Can you install applications on your jump server? Ansible is quite scalable for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Use ssh eg

```
$ echo date | ssh remote-server
Wed Jan  2 22:38:21 AEST 2019
```

Obviously instead of 'echo date' you could 'cat some-big-file-of commands'

Comment: So in that case I need to create tunnel to final server first and than to execute this command. I think I will give a try. But I will check if there is some other ways as well. Thanks!